# SQL database layout

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I'm trying to set up a database to hold information about a tournament. I'm new to SQL and was looking for some feedback on my design.

The database has to hold player names, games played, scores, player wins and games still to be played.

My current design is -

**Players:**

PlayerId Name Wins

**Games:**

GameId Player1 Player2 Player1Score Player2Score Played

Is this okay or is there a better way to set things up?

Answer (score 0):

I think that is quite ok, remember always to create always an id that can help you retrieve all the informations you need.

Table Player

```
idPlayer| Name |Win | Lose
```

Table Games

```
IdGame| idPlayer as Player1 | idPlayer as Player2 | P1_Score | P2_Score |MatchPlayed
```

Like this you can retreive all the info about a single player and a match or all the matches disputed by a player.

Comment: Do you need a column for whether the match has been played, or could I just return true or false whether the two scores == 0? Both scores will never be 0 if the match has been played

Comment: Yeah you can add a column match played with 0 or 1 o T or F

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the project you want to do for sure, but i think it's good the only change I would made is the name of the tables:
**Players to Player**
It doesn't matter much but think you should use the singular, just my oppinion.
Then do a trigger to update the Wins field in players and the lose field if you want to create it.